# consecutive ajax calls freeze chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

i got a strange one. I have to make several consecutive ajax calls, and when a call is complete i update a progress bar. This works perfectly on FF but on the rest of the browsers what happens is that the screen freezes until all the calls are complete.

I am not executing the calls in a loop, but by using some sort of recursion cause there's a lot of checking that needs to be done and a loop is not convenient.

When i tried the same thing using a loop the outcome was more or less the same. Chrome or IE did not update the screen until all the ajax requests where done.

What i noticed is that it works ok on FF and opera, but chrome (safari too i suppose) and IE9 are behaving strange. Also on Chrome, during these requests, the response body of the previous request is empty and will remain like that until all requests are done.

Any ideas?

Code is extensive, but here goes. There is a wrapper to ajax, $(db).bind is a callback for success. db.records is the Json result. Model is an object holding several controller functions

```
$(db).bind('tokenComplete',function(){
var x = db.records;
if (!x.success) { model.callRollBack(); return false; }
var next = parseInt(x.get.num)+ 1;
if (typeof x.post.tokens[next] != 'undefined') {
    model.executeToken(next,x.post);
}
else { 
    model.progressCurrent.find('div.report').html('all done!!');
}
```

});

```
model = {
drawProgressBarsTotal : function(el,i,v) {
    var p = Math.floor(100 * i / versions.total);
    el.find('span').html(p);
    el.find('div.report').html('updating to : ' + v.version);
    el.find('.changeLog').html(v.changeLog);
    el.find('.changeLog').parents('div').show();
    el.find('img').css({'background-position': 100 - p + '% 100%'});
},
executeToken : function(i,x) {
    if (this.fail == true) { return; }
    this.drawProgressBarsCurrent(this.progressCurrent,i+1,x);
    db.trigger = 'tokenComplete';
    db.data = x;
    db.url = dbDefaults.url + '?num='+i+'&action='+x.tokens[i];//bring the first
    $(db).loadStore(db);
}
```

}

loadStore :

```
$.dataStore = function( ds ) {

    $.fn.loadStore = function(ds){
        $.ajax({
            type: ds.method,
            url: ds.url,
            data: ds.data,
            dataType: ds.dataType,
            cache:false,
            async:true,
            timeout:ds.timeout?ds.timeout:10000,                
            queue: "autocomplete",

            contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
            accepts: {
                xml: "application/xml, text/xml",
                json: "application/json, text/json",
                _default: "*/*"
            },
            beforeSend:function(){
                loadStatus = true;
            },
            success: function(data) {
                loadStatus = false;

                if(data)
                {ds.records=data;}
                $(ds).trigger(ds.trigger);
            },              
            error: function()
            {                   
                loadStatus = false;         
                $(ds).trigger('loadError');

            }
        });//END AJAX
    };//END LOADSTORE

    try {
        return ds;
    } finally {
        ds = null;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: make sure on your open method your using async without seeing the code no more can be said

Comment: async is on, and the code (displayed above) works fine. The browsers are not updated though

Comment: Show the loop and Ajax call...

Comment: there is no loop, just when it comes back from the ajax, it checks if there is a next call to be made like so
 if (typeof x.post.tokens[next] != 'undefined') {
    model.executeToken(next,x.post);
}
then goes back to the executeToken which makes the call via $(db).loadStore(db). This is just a wrapper for ajax. I have added it above

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Chrome freezes up while FireFox and Opera work fine. Did you ever get a resolution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't followed your entire code, but it sounds like your problem may be related to continuous code execution. Typically the UI will not update during continuous code execution. To fix this, any call to a setTimeout() or any ajax calls should allow the browser time to update the UI. Basically, you must stop the code briefly, then start it again.

```
function updateUI () {
   // change ui state
   document.setTimeout( updateUI, 1 );
}
```

If I am off base here, let me know.